# Substitution integral with sines and cosines

Tags: integration

Could I ask you guys to help me out with this?

$\displaystyle\int \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{2+\cos x}}dx$

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: set $2+\cos x=t$; then $dt=-\sin x\,dx$; can you do $\int t^{-1/2}\,dt$?

Comment: Hmm, my result is $\frac{2}{3\sqrt{(2+cosx)^3}}$, but I am not sure about it. Btw, shouldn't be "-" in front of the integral?

Comment: @user2932090 After the substitution you get $\int-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt=-\int t^{-1/2}\,dt$. This integral is not what you got, because it is $-2\sqrt{t}$.

Comment: Aah, the result is wrong, I found it should be just $-2\sqrt{2+cosx}+c$

Comment: @user2932090 Correct.

Comment: But how is possible in the result is "-" and where did disappear the "3"?

Comment: @user2932090 Where should a $3$ appear? You have $\int t^k\,dt=\frac{t^{k+1}}{k+1}$ (for $k\ne-1$), in this case with $k=-1/2$. Since $-\frac{1}{2}+1=\frac{1}{2}$, no $3$ is to be found.